# How to force relative pathing with Struts 2.1 and Dojo?

Tags: ajax, dojo, struts2, relative-path

I upgraded from Struts 2.0.6 to 2.1.6 and converted all my Ajax themes to plugins.  Everything works except the pathing has changed from relative to absolute.  For example, here is the rendered HTML before upgrade:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../struts/simple/dojoRequire.js"></script>
```

And here it is after upgrade:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/myApp/struts/ajax/dojoRequire.js"></script>
```

Somehow the absolute "/myApp" is getting used instead of the relative ".." path.

Does anyone know how to force it to use the old-way of pathing?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: How are you putting the script tag in the page?

Comment: Here is the top of the page:

<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s"  uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

<html>
<head>

<title>Home</title>

<s:head/>
<sx:head/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add baseRelativePath="../struts/dojo"

to the sx: head tag to get it to work.

I think this is actually a bug in the Dojo plugin (or at least should be documented that the 2.1 upgrade changes things, but I am happy it is working.

Scott